# Update multiple columns with the selected value from multi select dropdown in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a multi dropdown list in mvc, I need to save the selected value in the same table but a different column in sql server

```
1.Fruits
    -Fruits A
        *Fruits B 

table A 
-------------------------
Fruits   |  Fruits 1  
-------------------------
Fruits A | Fruits B
```

Comment: What is the maximum number of items user can select?

Comment: maximum number of item user can select is 4, meaning there will be 2 more column in the table A

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? Any errors? How are you writing to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the selected values as comma separated like (Fruits1,Fruits2 etc). Then in SQL you can split up the Comma separated string as per your table columns.

Latest version SQL support the split functionality as default.